# When i compile I keep getting this error message '.class' expected for this line this.hand = Card[] hand; I don't know what to do to change it

Tags: java

I looked on websites for help but I still can't find an answer to for this problem.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

private Card[] hand;
private int placement;
private Strategy myStrategy;

public Player( Card hand, Strategy myStrategy ) {
    this.hand = Card[] hand;
    this.myStrategy = myStrategy;
    placement = 0;
}

public void giveCard( Card newCard ) {
    hand[placement] = new Card();
    placement++;
}

public int takeTurn() {
    return myStrategy.hitOrStand();
}

public int value() {
    int value = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < placement; i++ ) {
        this.value = value + hand[i].value();
    }

    return value;
}
}
```

I'm so confused on how to change this. Can somebody help me to make sure that I have it right.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
this.hand = Card[] hand;
```

is illegal. You could try

```
this.hand = new Card[] { hand };
```

**NOTE** You still have only room for one Card in your Hand array at that point. I recommend that you use a Collection type (I would probably use a Set or a List myself) for your hand.

Comment: I have tried to make the changes but its still saying the same thing.